# An error occurs when I use ?? 0 What is this error for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This error is displayed when I enter this bold code snippet What are the drawbacks?(int)Course.SubGroup??0

```
 public void OnGet(long id)
    {
        Course=  _CourseApplication.GetCourse(id);
        var groups = _CourseApplication.GetSarGroup();
        ViewData["Groups"] = new SelectList(groups,"Value","Text",Course.GroupId);

        var subGrous = _CourseApplication.GetSubGroup(long.Parse(groups.First().Value));
        ViewData["SubGroups"] = new SelectList(subGrous, "Value", "Text",**(int)Course.SubGroup??0**);
```

This error is displayed
error CS0019: Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'

Comment: The `??` operator only works with reference types. `int` is not a reference type - it's a value type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable on the left side of `??` operator has to be nullable (which means that you can assign null to it), in your case `Course.SubGroup` should be of type `int?` not `int`. And no need cast to int, change like below:

```
ViewData["SubGroups"] = new SelectList(subGrous, "Value", "Text",Course.SubGroup??0);
```